# Which steps should be followed to integrate two different software process models to each other?

Tags: scrum, personal-software-process

Recently, I am working on my course project, the topic is the creation of a new hybrid software process model by integrating Scrum and Team Software Process (TSP). Integration of these two models will be based on the SEMAT Essence Kernel Framework.

I am wondering:

- Which steps should be followed for this integration (like
  determination of the roles and artifacts in these two models)?
- What should be the criteria to decide on good sides?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think I can answer this question is by quoting the [agile manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

"Individuals and interactions over processes and tools"

Agile is about people, teamwork and craftsmanship. It's about involving the customer closely to figure out what really is needed - and delivering that, in small increments of working software. Agile is inspect and adapt, based on experimental delivery and the feedback and evidence that comes from that.

Trust yourself. Work closely together and you can do this. The best learning often comes from doing. :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12075589)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help stackoverflow be the best it can be. In this case the link is very relevant, there is a direct quote from the (very concise) reference that is linked and the page linked is also one of the most stable link url:s on the internet. I also elaborate on why I quoted what I did, so in this case using a link is just fine. No moderation needed.